# Redux-like implementation in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-safety

I need to write a custom reducer utility. It should take a dictionary of reducers and a publish subject to return a state, with a `dispatch` method to dispatch actions and notify the publish subject.

It should be 100% type-checked with TypeScript, compatible with `strict` compiler options, and should only use type-inference when applicable.

[Link in the TypeScript Playground to see the types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Action%3CT%20%3D%20string%2C%20S%20extends%20%7B%7D%20%3D%20any%3E%20%3D%20S%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Reducer%3CS%20%3D%20any%2C%20A%20extends%20Action%20%3D%20Action%3E%20%3D%20(state%3A%20S%20%7C%20undefined%2C%20action%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20S%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Reducers%3CS%20%3D%20any%2C%20A%20extends%20Action%20%3D%20Action%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Reducer%3CS%2C%20A%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ReducerState%3CR%3E%20%3D%20R%20extends%20Reducer%3Cinfer%20S%2C%20any%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20S%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ReducersActions%3CR%20extends%20Reducers%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20R%5D%3A%20R%5BK%5D%20extends%20Reducer%3Cany%2C%20infer%20A%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%7D%5Bkeyof%20R%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20StoresState%3CR%20extends%20Reducers%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20R%5D%3A%20ReducerState%3CR%5BK%5D%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Atype%20Stores%3CR%20extends%20Reducers%3E%20%3D%20StoresState%3CR%3E%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dispatch(action%3A%20ReducersActions%3CR%3E)%3A%20void%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Subject%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20next(object%3A%20T)%3A%20void%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createReducer%3CT%20extends%20Reducers%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20reducers%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20publish%3A%20Subject%3CStores%3CT%3E%3E%0D%0A)%3A%20Stores%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20state%3A%20Partial%3CStores%3CT%3E%3E%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20state.dispatch%20%3D%20function%20dispatch(action)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.keys(reducers)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.forEach(key%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20state%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20reducers%5Bkey%5D(state%5Bkey%5D%2C%20action)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20publish.next(state%20as%20Stores%3CT%3E)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20state.dispatch(%7Btype%3A%20''%7D%20as%20Action)%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20state%20as%20Stores%3CT%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Test%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace%20Actions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20type%20AddTodo%20%3D%20Action%3C'add-todo'%2C%20%7Btodo%3A%20string%7D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20type%20RemoveTodo%20%3D%20Action%3C'remove-todo'%2C%20%7Bindex%3A%20number%7D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20type%20Todos%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20AddTodo%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20RemoveTodo%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20type%20ChangeInput%20%3D%20Action%3C'change-input'%2C%20%7Binput%3A%20string%7D%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20type%20All%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20Todos%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20ChangeInput%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20todos(todos%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%2C%20action%3A%20Actions.Todos)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20switch(action.type)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'add-todo'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%5B...todos%2C%20action.todo%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'remove-todo'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20todos.filter((_%2C%20i)%20%3D%3E%20i%20%3D%3D%3D%20action.index)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20todos%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20input(input%3A%20string%20%3D%20''%2C%20action%3A%20Actions.ChangeInput)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20switch(action.type)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'change-input'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20action.input%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20input%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20state%20%3D%20createReducer(%7Btodos%2C%20input%7D%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20next%3A%20(%7Btodos%2C%20input%7D)%20%3D%3E%20console.log('state'%2C%20%7Btodos%2C%20input%7D)%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Astate.dispatch(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'change-input'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20input%3A%20'do%20something'%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Astate.dispatch(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'add-todo'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20todo%3A%20state.input%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A).

**Implementation**

```
type Action<T = string, S extends {} = any> = S & {
    type: T
}

type Reducer<S = any, A extends Action = Action> = (state: S | undefined, action: A) => S

interface Reducers<S = any, A extends Action = Action> {
    [key: string]: Reducer<S, A>
}

type ReducerState<R> = R extends Reducer<infer S, any>
    ? S
    : never

type ReducersActions<R extends Reducers> = {
    [K in keyof R]: R[K] extends Reducer<any, infer A>
        ? A
        : never
}[keyof R]

type StoresState<R extends Reducers> = {
    [K in keyof R]: ReducerState<R[K]>
}
type Stores<R extends Reducers> = StoresState<R> & {
    dispatch(action: ReducersActions<R>): void
}

interface Subject<T> {
    next(object: T): void
}

function createReducer<T extends Reducers>(
    reducers: T,
    publish: Subject<Stores<T>>
): Stores<T> {
    const state: Partial<Stores<T>> = {}

    state.dispatch = function dispatch(action) {
        Object
            .keys(reducers)
            .forEach(key =>
                state[key] = reducers[key](state[key], action)
            )

        publish.next(state as Stores<T>)
    }
    state.dispatch({type: ''} as Action)

    return state as Stores<T>
}
```

**Test code**

```
namespace Actions {
    export type AddTodo = Action<'add-todo', {todo: string}>
    export type RemoveTodo = Action<'remove-todo', {index: number}>
    export type Todos =
        | AddTodo
        | RemoveTodo

    export type ChangeInput = Action<'change-input', {input: string}>

    export type All =
        | Todos
        | ChangeInput
}

function todos(todos: string[] = [], action: Actions.Todos) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'add-todo':
            return [...todos, action.todo]
        case 'remove-todo':
            return todos.filter((_, i) => i === action.index)
    }

    return todos
}

function input(input: string = '', action: Actions.ChangeInput) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'change-input':
            return action.input
    }

    return input
}
const state = createReducer({todos, input}, {
    next: ({todos, input}) => console.log('state', {todos, input})
})

state.dispatch({
    type: 'change-input',
    input: 'do something'
})

state.dispatch({
    type: 'add-todo',
    todo: state.input
})
```

- Can it be simplified? (e.g. less use of generics, get rid of TypeScript 2.8+ requirement for `infer`, etc..)
- Can I prevent `reducers` in the  `createReducer` function from having a `dispatch` property?
- Do you have any other suggestions/improvements?